# Keras custom data generator is very slow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am training an autoencoder with Keras custom data generator. Data is big enough to not fit into the memory.

Generator:

```
class Mygenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.x) / float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]

        # read your data here using the batch lists, batch_x and batch_y
        x = [np.reshape(np.load(filename),(52,52,1)) for filename in batch_x] # load array and reshape to fit input layer
        y = [np.reshape(np.load(filename),(52,52,1)) for filename in batch_y] # load array and reshape to fit input layer
        return np.array(x), np.array(y)
```

Model fit_generator:

```
XTRAINFILES = glob.glob("C:\\x_train\\*.npy") 
YTRAINFILES = glob.glob("C:\\y_train\\*.npy")
XTESTFILES = glob.glob("C:\\x_test\\*.npy") 
YTESTFILES = glob.glob("C:\\y_test\\*.npy") 

autoencoder_model.fit_generator(Mygenerator(XTRAINFILES, YTRAINFILES, 128),
                    epochs=EPOCHES, workers=8, steps_per_epoch=ceil( len(XTRAINFILES) / 128)
                    validation_data=Mygenerator(XTESTFILES, YTESTFILES, 128),
                    validation_steps=ceil( len(XTESTFILES) / 128),
                    callbacks=[tb_output, checkpoint_callback])
```

Keras gives an ETA between 2 and 3 hours. testing without the custom generator with just a little bit less data to fit in the memory had ETA of 20 to 30 mins per epoch.

Insights about PC specs:

- GPU: Geforce RTX 2080 Ti
- Ram: 128 GB

**Attempted solution:** adding `workers = 8` to the fit generator, improved the time a little but still not close enough to the expected

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. did you figure out how to solve it ?

Comment: There's basically no solution if you are using custom generator. That's a tradeoff that you have to accept between having the model running on low hardware and speed of the data being fed into the generator which also depends on external factors like I/O speed happening on your hard drive. I spent a lot of time searching this. The only solution I didn't try is using `use_multiprocessing=True` . At that time, that flag wasn't working properly on Windows. You can give it a try now and let me know if things got better ;)

Answer (score -3):

It seems there is an issue with `fit_generator()` function, so you should rather use `fit()`.

You can also try disabling the eager execution with:

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

Issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33024#issuecomment-539239067).